# Set color for closing tag in atom

Tags: html, regex, syntax, tags, atom-editor

I started theming the Atom editor. I stumbled upon the part where I want to be able to set up the color only for the closing html tag. What I have now:

[image: screenshot 1]

What I have when I 'color' all the closing tags:

[image: screenshot 2]

As far I could figure out, I would need a custom grammar for the Atom to
find which tags are the closing one's. I tried to modify the `vue.js` grammar to achieve the result, but failed.

Answer (score 0):

The following regex should match your closing tags:

```
<\/\w+>
```

If you want to capture the angle brackets within the regex, then you could use:

```
(<\/)\w+(>)
```